# Is tensor product of two global sections commutative in the tensor product sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on an algebraic curve $X$. Since $\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{L}$ is 
the sheafification of the presheaf $(\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{L})^{pre}$, we have a morphism
$$
\varphi:H^0(\mathcal{L})\otimes H^0(\mathcal{L})\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{L}).
$$ 
Let $s,t\in H^0(\mathcal{L})$. We do not necessarily have that $s\otimes t=t\otimes s$.

Does the equality $\varphi(s\otimes t)=\varphi(t\otimes s)$ hold?

Comment: Well, $\mathcal{L}$ is of rank $1$, so $$\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{L} = \mathrm{Sym}^2 \mathcal{L}.$$

Comment: This is a local statement so one reduces to the case $\mathcal{L} \simeq \mathcal{O}_{X}$.